# Localized menu bar item strings in iTunes

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

The following code will disable shuffle mode in iTunes:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        click menu item "Off" of menu 1 of menu item "Shuffle" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Controls" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

However it only works if the system language is English.
I would prefer not to use indices, so I tried using `localized string of` on `"Off"`, `"Shuffle"` and `"Controls"`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Test code:

```
tell application "iTunes" to get localized string of "Shuffle"
```

Is there another way of getting the localized string or at least avoid having to hardcode the menu bar item indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the key's name because **iTunes** don't use the english menu's title as the key name.

To know the key name (the "**Localizable.strings**" file in the iTunes bundle is a plist format):

- Open the TextWrangler application, drag the
  "**/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/Localizable.strings**"
  file and drop it on the icon of the TextWrangler application.

  Search "string>Shuffle<" in the document to get the key
  name.

---

```
set iTunesPath to "/Applications/iTunes.app" as POSIX file as alias
set contr to localized string "8d2vvyy7c7" in bundle iTunesPath
set shuf to localized string "atmqaez8y8" in bundle iTunesPath
set off to localized string "ve0frz64yk" in bundle iTunesPath
activate application "iTunes"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "iTunes"
        click menu item off of menu 1 of menu item shuf of menu 1 of menu bar item contr of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I opened the Accessibility Inspector in Xcode's Development Tools to see what objects I could find enumerating through `UI elements`

First I ran this to get a good idea, which returns the name I need to start, `menu bar 1`

```
tell application "System Events to tell process "iTunes"
    UI elements
end tell
```

After this you can get a list of elements to work with, once you run `tell menu bar 1` to display its `UI elements`.

`{menu bar item "Apple" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "iTunes" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "Edit" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "Controls" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "Store" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events", menu bar item "Help" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events"}`

I'm thinking next you could do use what is returned here to iterate through and find the item, store this in a variable and make it less dependent on name, since the index won't change based on the language and this can be verified in `Accessibility Inspector` which will show object references.

I tried something along these lines:

```
tell menu bar 1
    set a to UI Elements
    return item 6 of a
end tell
```

Output:

```
menu bar item "Controls" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events"
```

All right, going further you will want to find the specific menu item and value. Which values are being affected by the language changes too.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "iTunes"
    tell menu bar 1
        set a to UI elements
        set b to item 6 of a
        set c to UI elements of b
        -- c = {menu "Controls" of menu bar item "Controls" of menu bar 1 of application process "iTunes" of application "System Events"}

        tell menu "Controls"
            set d to item 16 of UI elements
            tell menu "Shuffle" of d
                --click menu item 1 (On)
                --click menu item 2 (Off)
        end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```